# java.nio.DirectByteBuffer to string without copying

Tags: java, nio

Is there a way of converting a java.nio.DirectByteBuffer into a String? i.e. without using `get(bytes[])`.

I tried converting it into a CharBuffer but then it uses 16bits for each char instead of 8.

Comment: No, each `String` owns its content. One way or another, a copy will be involved (some internal optimizations not included).

Comment: There will be a copy, however you do it.

Comment: I'm happy to accept an answer.